# Getting today's distinct date from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, mysqli

I'm trying to select the distinct IPs from all time from today's date, and it returned 39 rows, but it's suppose to be less, since some of the IPs aren't distinct since they visited from before today. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (ip), DATE AS tempDate
FROM  `ipAll` 
HAVING tempDate =  '2015-12-29'
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of HAVING clause use WHERE CLAUSE and get rid of the quotes on the table name.
HAVING CLAUSE is used when you use GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Those are not quotes, rather mysql escape character. there is nothing wrong using them with table/column name.

Comment: Oh well thanks for telling me that, I thought ' ' are used for string  and        " " are used for alias.

Comment: `""` are ANSI standard escape sequence but specific RDBMS may have their own like mysql uses backtique the one you seeing and MSSQL uses `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `WHERE` condition rather like below. Assuming that you have a `date` type column named `tempdate` where you store the visited datetime.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip
FROM  `ipAll` 
WHERE tempDate =  CURDATE();
```

Comment: No. This returned the same exact result as my query. 39 rows.

Comment: Also date is the column name.

Comment: Also, I don't want to select the distinct date from today. I want to select the distinct date from ALL TIME, that VISITED today.